# Linux: How to get full name of shared object just loaded from the constructor?

Tags: linux, dll, object, constructor, shared

On Windows, several arguments are passed to the DllMain constructor:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(  
  __in  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  
  __in  DWORD fdwReason,  
  __in  LPVOID lpvReserved  
);
```

From hinstDLL I can get the fully qualified file name of the DLL itself using GetModuleFileName():

```
LPTSTR str = new TCHAR[256];  
int libNameLength = GetModuleFileName(hinstDLL, str, 256);  
delete[] str;
```

In the example above, str now contains the full name of the DLL just loaded, e.g., C:\Windows\System32\MyFile.dll.

On Linux, no arguments are passed to the shared object constructor:

```
void `__attribute__` ((constructor)) on_load(void);
```

How do I get the full name of the DLL in this case? Extra credit if your solution works on Mac, too. :-)

Comment: I don't know that there is a good way.  My question in situations like this is "Why do you want to know?".  By stepping back a level you may find there's a path to your real goal without taking the step that's currently blocking you.

Comment: Good question. I want to know, because I'm developing a CSP and a PKCS#11 module (DLL files) both of which need to verify their own integrity when they're loaded. Both DLL files are loaded by the OS, so my entry point is the constructor.

Currently, the best idea I have for verifying the integrity of the DLL file is to calculate a hash of the DLL file in the constructor and then send that hash off to a central server which can verify the correctness of the hash. However, I need the file name of the DLL in order to be able to calculate the hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `dladdr` function might do what you want. From the man page:

> The  function  dladdr()  takes  a function pointer and tries to resolve
>   name and file where it  is  located.   Information  is  stored  in the
>   `Dl_info` structure:
>
> ```
> typedef struct {
>     const char *dli_fname;  /* Pathname of shared object that
>                                contains address */
>     void       *dli_fbase;  /* Address at which shared object
>                                is loaded */
>     const char *dli_sname;  /* Name of nearest symbol with address
>                                lower than addr */
>     void       *dli_saddr;  /* Exact address of symbol named
>                                in dli_sname */
> } Dl_info;
> ```
>
> If no symbol matching addr could be found, then `dli_sname` and
>   `dli_saddr` are set to `NULL`.
>
> `dladdr()` returns 0 on error, and non-zero on success.

So you just give it a function pointer (like the address of the constructor itself), and it will give you the filename and a bunch of other information. Here's some sample code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void on_load(void) {
    Dl_info dl_info;
    dladdr(on_load, &dl_info);
    fprintf(stderr, "module %s loaded\n", dl_info.dli_fname);
}
```

---

EDIT: It looks like this function exists on OS X, too, with the same semantics.

Comment: Yes, I'm so happy that the way we both thought of isn't the right answer.  :-)

Comment: This method does not work on Android: `dli_fname` contains only the file name, and not the full path.

Answer (score 1):

One supremely ugly and horrible way to do this is to look through /proc/pid/maps and look for the mapping that encompasses the address of the `on_load` function being executed.

Comment: I started going down this road yesterday, and I've not dismissed it *completely* yet, because it's currently the only viable solution I know. It sends chills down my spine, too, though.